# Place WebView below GridView in Android Layout?

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, xamarin.android

Below is the xml layout for my Android App.  I am trying to positions a webview below the gridview on the screen.

Can anyone help explain what I need to do to get that to work?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/db1_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/HomePage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/Grid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        <WebView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/webView1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think two minor changes will help make this work for you.  First, when creating a LinearLayout, the `android:orientation` attribute is required to indicate whether the children should be added horizontally or vertically.  Since you want one view on top of the other, add `android:orientation=vertical` to the HomePage LinearLayout.  Second, your GridView currently has a `android:layout_height` of `fill_parent`.  This will cause it to expand vertically and fill up the entirety of the LinearLayout, which will keep your WebView from being displayed.  Try changing this attribute to `wrap_content`.

Making the height of both children `wrap_content` could possibly cause you to have some empty space in your app.  If you need either the GridView or WebView to take up all of the empty space in the view, you can use the `android:layout_weight` attribute.  Assign the view you want to expand to fill all remaining space after the rest are drawn the attribute like this: `android:layout_weight=1`.  (Here, the 1 represents 100% of the remaining space)  If you want more granular control over what percentage of the parent your children occupy, look into using decimal values with the `android:layout_weight` attribute or `android:weightSum` on the parent in conjunction with a `android:layout_weight` on each of the children.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Forgot to mention, if you're using `layout_weight` for your view, set the `layout_height` of that view to 0dip.  You normally should not used pixel values to define your height and width in Android, but 0dip helps the system determine how to inflate your view when used in conjunction with `layout_weight`.  Keeping it as wrap_content shouldn't hurt, but 0dip is more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in Gridview

Set orientation attribute in inner linear layout.

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Give fixed height of WebView and set   `android:layout_weight=""` in both child.

Try below code and change according to your webview height and grid view height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/db1_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/HomePage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/Grid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center"
           android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        <WebView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In above code I give Height of `WebView 200dp` change according to your requirement.

Comment: Assigning a layout_weight with a fixed height is not good, as only one of the two will be honored.  When you assign a layout_weight for a widget in a vertical text view, you should set the height to 0dip, that way the system knows to grow the view based on weight and height will not conflict.  As a general rule, fixed values should not be used for layout_height and layout_width, in order to better support multiple screen sizes.